# Getting syntax error on CAST & COALESCE function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, coalesce

```
SELECT
    CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)
FROM
    'peppy-generator-406617.customer_data.customer_purchase'
ORDER BY
    CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) DESC
```

I tried to get the purchase price in ascending order but I got syntax error. I could not understand the reason for getting the error. Need help to understand the mistake.

Comment: `ORDER BY` with a space. `DESC` = descending, not ascending.

Comment: not sure but I would guess it's either the quoted table name or an invalid cast; probably the quoted table name, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: So what’s the syntax error?

Comment: use `\`peppy-generator-406617.customer_data.customer_purchase\`` instead of `'peppy-generator-406617.customer_data.customer_purchase'`

Answer (score 0):

You're using a string for a table name. Table and column names are identifiers; identifiers are quoted differently. Either use no quotes, or use `` ` ``to quote.

To avoid repeating column expressions, you can refer to columns by their position in the select clause.

```
SELECT
    CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)
FROM
    `peppy-generator-406617.customer_data.customer_purchase`
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) AS x1
FROM
    'peppy-generator-406617.customer_data.customer_purchase'
ORDER BY
    x1 DESC
```

Comment: You can also do `order by 1 desc`. I don't think this solves the issue, `order by` can take an expression. The problem is likely using a string for a table name.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**